# WP - вывод 7 постов от актуальной даты

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-query

У меня есть рубрика, в которой много постов. Посты начинаются, к примеру, с "21 декабря 2019 года". Посты эти опубликованы заранее, но их нужно вывести на сайте так: сегодняшняя дата + 7 постов после нее. Остальные показывать не нужно.

У меня есть этот код:

```
class GoroskopController
```

{

```
static function get_data($parent_id, $number, $heading, $heading_color = 'dark')
{
    $loop = new \WP_Query(GoroskopModule::loop_args($parent_id, $number));

    if ($loop->have_posts()) :

        echo '<div class="goroskop-block mb30">';
        echo '<div class="block-heading-color-small -' . $heading_color . ' font-sans">' . $heading . '</div>';
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            $this_date = self::this_gor(get_the_title());

            include "templates/block.php";

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
        echo ($parent_id == 156) ? '<div class="view-more font-sans"><a href="' . get_category_link($parent_id) . '">' . esc_html__('Смотреть все', 'grimple_core') . '</a></div>' : '';
        echo '</div>';

    endif;
}

static function now_date()
{
    $m = [
        'января' => '01',
        'февраля' => '02',
        'марта' => '03',
        'апреля' => '04',
        'мая' => '05',
        'июня' => '06',
        'июля' => '07',
        'августа' => '08',
        'сентября' => '09',
        'октября' => '10',
        'ноября' => '11',
        'декабря' => '12'
    ];

    return $m;
}

static function this_gor($title)
{
    $gor_date = explode(' ', $title);

    $m = self::now_date();
    $this_date = date('d.m.Y');

    $day = (mb_strlen($gor_date[0],'UTF-8') == 1) ? '0' . $gor_date[0] : $gor_date[0];
    $month = $gor_date[1];
    $year = $gor_date[2];

    foreach ($m as $key => $value) {
        if ($month == $key)
            $month = $value;
    }

    $sep = '.';
    $gor_out_date = $day . $sep . $month . $sep . $year;

    $this_gor = ($this_date == $gor_out_date) ? true : '';

    return $this_gor;
}
```

}

который берет из тайтла те же примерные "21 декабря 2019 года" и делает из них 21.12.2019 . и так со всеми.

И вот тут есть проблема, для вывода сегодняшнего поста + 7 после него, расчитаных кодом выше я использовал:

```
class GoroskopModule
```

{

```
static function loop_args($parent_id, $number)
{
    $args = [
        'cat' => $parent_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 7,
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'date_query' => array('after' => date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-2 days')) )
    ];

    return $args;
}
```

}

но он выводит 7 постов не основываясь на калькуляции первого кода.  Надо чтобы это работало так http://prntscr.com/q3oxc2 а не так http://prntscr.com/q3oxnh

Comment: Много написал, но что у тебя не получается то? Так а не так?

Comment: смотри: у меня есть много постов на будущее, с 27 ноября по 29 декабря. опубликованы они все практически в один день. во всех них h1 начинаются с: 27 *месяц* 2019. первая часть кода конвертит 27 *месяц* 2019 в 27.11.2019 если пост например был с h1 "27 ноября 2019".  нужно выводить строго 7 постов от актуальной даты, если например сегодня 27 ноября то: все посты с названием 28 ноября 2019, 29 ноября 2019 и тд. причина почему не работает 'date_query' => array('after' => date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-2 days')) ) в том что посты опубликованы в один день а эта часть кода делает выборку по дате.

Comment: Да, но по дате публикации, не по h1

Comment: В каком поле у тебя ходится дата?

Comment: в заголовке http://prntscr.com/q3qajb

Comment: или же как вариант... уже опубликованным статьям выставить дату публикации равную ее заголовку, это я вручную сделаю, к примеру статье с заголовком "29 декабря 2019" поставлю дату публикации 29.12.2019. Но тогда у нее изменится статус на запланированную, а значит она не появится на сайте пока не придет эта дата. А я хочу чтобы она индексировалась прямо сейчас. Можно ли как то сделать чтобы запланированные статьи ОПРЕДЕЛЕННОЙ КАТЕГОРИИ публиковались сразу независимо от того, что дата публикации у них выставлена передним числом?

Comment: Тебе нужно поле, куда будешь записывать дату в нормальном формате. И потом просто в meta_query по полю делаешь сравнение больше или меньше, как тебе нужно будет

Comment: тоже вариант. попробую, спасибо!

Comment: сделал через advanced custom fields, который так и так уже использовался на сайте, добавив доп. поле даты и проставив всем  статьям нужную дату чтобы они выводились по порядку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class GoroskopModule
{
static function loop_args($parent_id, $number)
{
$time = current_time( 'timestamp' ); 
$today = date('Ymd');

$args = array (
'post_status'            => 'publish', 
'orderby'                => 'meta_value', 
'meta_key'               => 'gor_date', 
'meta_value'             => $time, 
'meta_compare'           => '>=',
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'gor_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
    ),
'order'                  => 'ASC', 
'posts_per_page'         => 7,
);

    return $args;
}
}
```

спасибо **Krya** за идею добавить нужную дату через доп.поля. с кодом выше теперь всё работает как надо;)

Comment: Можно еще скрыть это поле и записывать туда при сохранении дату исходя из заголовка.